# How to check if quantity is more or less on a table?

Tags: vba, ms-access

I need to check if I have enough quantity of a specific product. How do I make it so the quantity that it checks is the one of the product in a textbox(txtIdProd).

This is my code:

```
Private Sub Cantidad_LostFocus()
Set myDatabase = CurrentDb()
Set myRs = myDatabase.OpenRecordset("TblProductos", dbOpenDynaset)
Dim cant As Integer
cant = txtCantidad
myRs.FindFirst "IDProducto=" & Me.txtIdProd
If myRs.NoMatch = False Then
    If cant > myRs("CantidadDisponible") Then
        Me.Label27.Visible = True
    End If
End If
Exit Sub
Me.Label27.Visible = False

End Sub
```

Comment: Why not use comboboxes instead of textboxes?

Comment: Shouldn't txtCantidad be `<=`  to CantidadDisponible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The FindFirst code should do exactly what you want. However, probably more efficient to filter the recordset.

```
Private Sub Cantidad_LostFocus()
    Dim cant As Integer
    If Not IsNull(Me.txtIDProd) Then
        Set myDatabase = CurrentDb()
        Set myRs = myDatabase.OpenRecordset("SELECT CantidadDisponible FROM TblProductos WHERE IDProducto=" & Me.txtIdProd, dbOpenDynaset)
        cant = rs!CantidadDisponible
    End If
    Me.Label27.Visible = Me.txtCantidad <= cant
End Sub
```

Another approach that doesn't use recordset:

`Me.Label27.Visible = Me.txtCantidad <= Nz(DLookup("CantidadDisponible", "TblProductos", "IDproducto=" & Nz(Me.txtIDProd,0)), 0)`

Note use of `<=` and assumes `txtCantidad` will not have 0.

Comment: Thanks, turns out I was just editing in an old sub because I changed the name and forgot. Will take a look as to how yours work tho.